# File inside a directory script

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a bash script to create a file in the directory name given. The script I wrote was:

```
D=$2
F=$1
D=`cat > "$F" && mkdir -v "$D"`
```

When I run the script passing the 2 arguments filename and pathname, it shows the file as being created but when I search for that file it not showing up in that directory.

Comment: It is not at all clear why you are overwriting the variable D with the output of `mkdir`, but if you do want to use process substitution, please recognize that backticks were deprecated sometime around 1990.  It is far cleaner to use: `D=$( mkdir -V "$D" && cat > "$D/$F" )`

Comment: @William Pursell Thanks for the update will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order or creation is wrong, use something like this:

```
~/temp5$ ls
script1.bash
~/temp5$ cat script1.bash 
D=$2
F=$1
mkdir -v "$D" && > "$D/$F"
~/temp5$ ./script1.bash newfilename newdirname
mkdir: created directory ‘newdirname’
~/temp5$ ls
newdirname  script1.bash
~/temp5$ ls newdirname/
newfilename
$
```

This is the final script:

```
D=$2
F=$1
mkdir -v "$D" && > "$D/$F"
```

Edit1:

```
$ ls
script.bash
~/temp5$ cat script.bash 
D=$2
F=$1
[[ "$D$F" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]] && mkdir -v "$D" && > "$D/$F"
~/temp5$ ./script.bash newfile123 newdir123
mkdir: created directory ‘newdir123’
~/temp5$ ls
newdir123  script.bash
~/temp5$ ls newdir123/
newfile123
~/temp5$ ./script.bash 'newfile;123' newdir123
~/temp5$ ./script.bash newfile.123 newdir123
~/temp5$ ls
newdir123  script.bash
~/temp5$ ls newdir123/
newfile123
$
```

This is the final script:

```
D=$2
F=$1
[[ "$D$F" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]] && mkdir -v "$D" && > "$D/$F"
```

`[[ "$D$F" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]]` ensures that both directory and file names have only these(1 or more alphanumeric/numeric) characters: a-z, A-Z and 0-9 using regular expressions.

Comment: one more thing i needed to ask is that how to check whether the filename and directory name you have entered is valid or not. I thought i would include it in the script with echo messages.

Comment: @DipankarDeka what is the critera to check if its valid or not?

Comment: criteria is that the filename can accept alphanumeric, numeric or both and the directory name criteria is also the same as filename criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You order of actions is wrong: you create the file before creating the directory. You should have done something like

```
 mkdir "$D"
 chdir "$D"
 cat > "$F"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create the directory and a blank file of desired name in provided location

```
mkdir -p $2 && touch $2/$1
```